# C++ Is "class Name*" a class pointer?

Tags: class, c++11, pointers, unreal-engine4

I was watching an unreal tutorial and encountered this line of code:

```
class UStaticMeshComponent*  Pickup;
```

It is a forwards declaration.
I have been studying c++ for a while and have not encountered anything like this before. I know about pointers and references,  but I never seen this format: class Name*. Are we creating a class pointer to another class? I tried searching for class names followed by a *, but the only result that appeared were about data types and pointers.

```
public:
    APickUp ();

    virtual void BeginPlay () override;

    virtual void tick ( float DeltaSeconds );

private:
    class UStaticMeshComponent* Pickup;
```

Comment: please don't post screenshots of code. Use text (as oposed to images) and format it as code (ctrl-k shortcut)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class UStaticMeshComponent*  Pickup;
```

This declares the type `class UStaticMeshComponent` and also declares the variable `Pickup` of type pointer to `UStaticMeshComponent`. So the above code is more or less equivalent with:

```
class UStaticMeshComponent;
UStaticMeshComponent*  Pickup;
```

Because at this point you don't have the definition of `UStaticMeshComponent` (just the declaration), `UStaticMeshComponent` is considered an incomplete type. There are a few things you can do with an incomplete type. One of them is declare pointers to them.

Comment: Is there any difference, if it is in the class as in the question? Is it than a forward declaration to a inner class or a class in the same namespace?

Answer (score 2):

When you are only using a pointer to a type, the type is not required to be complete, so this works fine even if `UStaticMeshComponent` has not been defined.  That means when this header is included in one of your cpp files, it should compile a bit faster than if `Pickup.h` were to include the header where `UStaticMeshComponent` is defined.

This speed up could be substantial depending on how big that header is, and how many times the include is avoided during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

The big confusion here is the difference between:

```
class UStaticMeshComponent*  Pickup;
```

and

```
class UStaticMeshComponent  *Pickup;
```

and even this:

```
class UStaticMeshComponent  *  Pickup;
```

, as in the example http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/#pointers_to_classes .

The difference is - bad practice. All supposed to mean the same thing but only the second example is correct, yet all of them work.

---

At least according to this:
 https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~eno/coding/CppCodingStandard.html

> place the * close to variable name not pointer type

I am a novice, I might be wrong. Please correct me if i am wrong.